# Unable to install yfinance

Tags: libxml2, yfinance

The package will not install.
In the command prompt I entered, 'pip install yfinance'

```
      C:\Users\gam19\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitw4g8q0z6.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: There was a recent update to yfinance to resolve this issue: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1222 . The new release was after this question. Maybe try to install again?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the wheel from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and install it (E.g. `pip install lxml‑4.9.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl`). Trying `pip install yfinance` might work after that.